# future or present in this case

Tags: future-tense

She has to tell her boss when she **will be** on holydays or when she **is** on holydays

I think the first one is better because you can ask the question she has to tell what not when

Comment: "Holidays " should be written like this.

Comment: We also usually say "on holiday", singular.

Comment: The first states that she will inform her boss before she goes on holiday; the second is ambiguous. She might already be on holiday when she lets her boss know.

Answer (score 1):

It is more clear that the trip is in the future if you say:
She has to tell her boss when she **will be** on holiday.

Also correct options:
She has to tell her boss when she **is going** on holiday.
She has to tell her boss when she **is going to be** on holiday.